# Separate a table in different tabs (HTML, PHP, JavaScript, etc)

Tags: php, javascript, html, tabs

Let me start off by saying that this is my first time working with PHP, HTML, JavaScript, and JQuery, so my experience is fairly lacking.

I am helping to build a Web Order Processor, which will display orders, dates, customers, and status. I am pulling orders from our database, and displaying them in a table. the Order Processor is being built in PHP.

Now, I've been asked to separate the table into different tabs, which will be labeled after the possible order statuses we have. Sort of like the tabs at the top of a browser.

My problem is quite a big one: I don't know where to start. I've been searching for a couple hours but I don't think I'm using the correct terminology.

Thank you all in advance. Any help would be appreciated, even if it's just pushing me in the right direction by giving me a couple things to search for.

Comment: Anything along the lines of http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/ ?

Comment: Use a plugin like suggested, especialy if first timer, or if you want something more funky try http://cooltabs.codeserenity.com/ then all you do is generate the markup in PHP and apply the plugin.

Comment: @gillesc Those are pretty neat tabs. I'm trying them out, now I need to work around the logic to fill my tables under each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest start with this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

First make sure your tabs are working with the simple static content
Second upgrade it so every time tab switched, it loads content from the database.

Depending on a tab you can customize request to the server with the status=(NEW,PROCESSES,REFUND ...), and do the query and return a proper data for the tab.

Hope it helps